# asp.net MVC3 Unit Testing - Role Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Unit testing of the role provider to fail.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void FindUsersInRole()
    {
        Mock<IUsersInRoleRepository> userInRoleMock = new Mock<IUsersInRoleRepository>();
        userInRoleMock.Setup(m => m.UsersInRoles).Returns(new UsersInRole[] {
            new UsersInRole { UserId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"), RoleId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa") },
            new UsersInRole { UserId = Guid.Parse("bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"), RoleId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa") },
            new UsersInRole { UserId = Guid.Parse("cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc"), RoleId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa") },
            new UsersInRole { UserId = Guid.Parse("dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd"), RoleId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa") },
            new UsersInRole { UserId = Guid.Parse("eeeeeeee-eeee-eeee-eeee-eeeeeeeeeeee"), RoleId = Guid.Parse("bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb") }
        }.AsQueryable());

        Mock<IRoleRepository> roleMock = new Mock<IRoleRepository>();
        roleMock.Setup(m => m.Roles).Returns(new Role[] {
            new Role { RoleId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"), RoleName = "test" },
            new Role { RoleId = Guid.Parse("bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"), RoleName = "admin" }
        }.AsQueryable());

        Mock<IUserRepository> userMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        userMock.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(new User[] {
            new User { UserId = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"), UserAccount = "abcdef" },
            new User { UserId = Guid.Parse("bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"), UserAccount = "bcdef" },
            new User { UserId = Guid.Parse("cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc"), UserAccount = "cdef" },
            new User { UserId = Guid.Parse("dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd"), UserAccount = "bcdf" },
            new User { UserId = Guid.Parse("eeeeeeee-eeee-eeee-eeee-eeeeeeeeeeee"), UserAccount = "abcde" }
        }.AsQueryable());

        RoleProvider target = new RoleProvider(userMock.Object, roleMock.Object, userInRoleMock.Object);

        string[] result = target.FindUsersInRole("test", "cde");

        Assert.AreEqual(result[0], "abcdef");
        Assert.AreEqual(result[1], "bcdef");
        Assert.AreEqual(result[2], "cdef");
    }
```

Unit Test Code

**string[] result = target.FindUsersInRole("test", "cde"); <-- error**

FindUsersInRole - Gets an array of user names in a role where the user name contains the specified user name to match.

System.NullReferenceException is raised and try to debug.

Why NullReferenceException?

PS - FindUsersInRole (RoleProvider)

```
public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string userAccountToMatch)
    {   
        Guid roleId = roleRepository.GetRole(roleName).RoleId; // RoleId Retrun.. NullReferenceException

        var roleInUsers = (from ru in usersInRoleRepository.UsersInRoles
                          where ru.RoleId == roleId
                          select ru.UserId).ToArray();

        var findUserResult = (from u in userRepository.Users
                              where roleInUsers.Contains(u.UserId) && u.UserAccount.Contains(userAccountToMatch)
                              select u.UserAccount).ToArray();

        return findUserResult;
    }
```

Comment: You will have to show how the `FindUsersInRole` method that you are trying to test is implemented.

Comment: Your cde is not a fake user in a mackUserAccount  .Please see my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Your **cde** is **not a fake user in a mackUserAccount** . So its return null.

try this below code string[] result = target.FindUsersInRole("test", "**abcdef**"); instead of

```
string[] result = target.FindUsersInRole("test", "cde");
```